# Pull out values from multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a multidimensional array which Im trying to pull all the values of a certain key and assign it to a variable.

This is the array:

```
Array
(
   [I_would_not_know_the_name_of_this_key] => Array
       (
           [interval] => 3600
           [display] => Once Hourly
       )
   [nor_this_one] => Array
       (
           [interval] => 43200
           [display] => Twice Daily
       )
   [nor_this_one] => Array
       (
           [interval] => 86400
           [display] => Once Daily
       )
)
```

I want to always get the [display] value even when I do not know what the upper level value is.

function which contains the array above, more schedules can be added which is why I said I would not always know the top level key: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_schedules

My code so far:

```
          $active_cron_schedules = wp_get_schedules(); //this is the 
          foreach ($active_cron_schedules as $key => $value) {
            echo $key;
          }

          ?>
```

This outputs for example: 'I_would_not_know_the_name_of_this_key', 'nor_this_one', 'nor_this_one', I need to get in deeper.

Arrays have always given me a run for my money in PHP can't figure out how to loop through it :(

Thank you

Comment: @PaulCrovella I have man, believe me I'm no novice dev, but arrays is something I have always had trouble with.

I have read the manual and I have some code but it's not giving out the information I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do will be solved with a `foreach()` loop or `array_column()` depending on your version of php. The variable part is hard to answer because you have not given an example of what you would be doing with the variable. A common mistake is to overwrite the variable in a loop, but if all you want are all the `display` values (or any other key), try:

```
function getValByKey($array, $getKey = 'display')
    {
        $new    =    array();
        foreach($array as $arr) {
            if(empty($arr[$getKey]))
                continue;

            $new[]    =    $arr[$getKey];
        }

        return $new;
    }

$result    =    array(
                    'key1'=> array('interval'=>1,'display'=>'1d'),
                    'key2'=> array('interval'=>2,'display'=>'2d'),
                    'key3'=> array('interval'=>3,'display'=>'3d')
                );
// To use
$display    =    getValByKey($result);
print_r($display);

// Array column has the same basic function, but
// Only available in PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7
$display    =    array_column($result,'display');

print_r($display);
```

Both give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1d
    [1] => 2d
    [2] => 3d
)
```

Comment: I updated with what I have so far. I'm basically not getting in as deep as I want into the array. Thanks for your help, havent tried your code above but Im sure with what I added above that im almost there?

Comment: You need to do `echo $value['display'];` because `$value` is the array you are looking for.

Comment: In my example, instead of echoing the value, it saves all the `display` values to a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Also in my example, if you wanted to echo them, you could then just use `implode()` like `echo '<div>'.implode('</div><div>',$display).'</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

whatever is the key, you dont even need to know it in a foreach.

here is a sample. $key can be anything. you just have to check for it s interval child element.

```
$interval_list = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $el) {
    if (isset($el['interval'])) {
        $interval_list[] = $el['interval'];
    }
}
```